# Is this the way proper to create jar file with multiple packages?

Tags: java, jar, applet

My class files's folder structure is like this :

```
.. classes/
      chartplottingview/(class files here belongs to chartplottingview package)
      chartplottingmodel/(somes class files here belong to chartplottingmodel package)
      chartplottingcontroller/(somes class files here belong to chartplottingcontroller package)
      chartplottingmain/Main.class belongs to chartplottingmain package
```

with the main class  in :

```
   chartplottingmain/Main.class
```

So, at window command line,  staying at folder ...classes, I created jar file like this :

```
  jar cfe chart.jar chartplottingmain/chartplottingmain.Main chartplottingmain/Main.class chartplottingview/filename.class so on...
```

My question is : is this the proper way to create the jar file because when i built jar file (to use with Java applet) like that the applet didn't work??

Comment: From the looks of it you have an extra path component in " chartplottingmain/chartplottingmain.Main". I think you mean "chartplottingmain.Main". But I don't understand how this relates to applets. What you are creating is an "executable jar".

Comment: yes, i create a jar file (chart.jar here ) to let it run in applet..

Comment: But executable jars and applets are two very different things. -e just marks the class as the entry point for anyone using the jar as an application either by running "java -jar jarfile.jar" directly or by clicking it in some filebrowser which has that process setup.

Comment: You don't need to name all the files explicitly. Something like `zip chart.jar chartplottingmain` does the job as well (yes, jar is zip, and adding the whole directory is that simple). It gets a bit more complicated if you want exclude some files.

Comment: @maartinus, and what about MANIFEST.MF?

Comment: What does `chartplottingmain.Main` extend?  There are only 2 classes in the J2SE that it could extend to be an applet.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: It extends JApplet..

Comment: Then, as mentioned by Marko & Maroe, you'll need to get access to the console, to get reports of exactly what does not work.  I can only guess at this stage what is going wrong, but from one of your previous questions:  This `File("D:/../hinhtu.jpg")` will not work in a standard (sand-boxed) applet, and would not work for a trusted applet when deployed on the internet.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How exactly does it not work? Do you have any kind of error message? The JAR used as an applet might need to be signed, for example.

Comment: When i run Main.java file as Applet in Eclipse, it works fine (with the chart appeared), but when I created the jar file, added it WebContent, configure the xml file, and run it in Browser, the chart didn't appear - it' was only the applet with the grey background blank..

Comment: You should start the Java Console. This will show you the details on why it failed to start up. Google for how to enable Java Console on your OS.

Comment: Try to run your applet in the Java Applet Viewer from your command line. There you'll see any stacktrace. See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/appletviewer.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a build tool that helps you building your output.

Have a look onto

- [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html)
- [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html)
- SBT

All these tools will help you to assemble your jar with as many packages as you want.